# Displaying buttons with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display two custom buttons in the same row and centered across the page. Currently, the buttons are showing on two different rows. Also, there has to be a better way of centering the buttons than with 'offset3'. Thank you in advance.

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 offset3"> 
            <a href="/bat-times/week">      
                <button class="btn btn-red"> Test 1</button>
            </a>    
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <a href="#"> 
                <button class="btn btn-yellow" onclick="checkTime()">Test 2</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: read the documentation on how to use the grid system

Comment: It does not show on two rows on large screens. What do you consider a proper way of centering two objects?

Comment: col-xs-6 text-right classes for first column, col-xs-6 text-left for second column.

Comment: Did you want this: http://jsbin.com/tofiho/1/

Answer (score 1):

You simply use Bootstrap's default class `.text-center` and that's it, keeping in mind the sum of your columns must be 12 (unless you use a custom number of columns). See code below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center"> 
            <a href="/bat-times/week">      
                <button class="btn btn-red "> Test 1</button>
            </a>    
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
            <a href="#"> 
                <button class="btn btn-yellow " onclick="checkTime()">Test 2</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And [see Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/mtL1RaJeWm). I have added some CSS for visualization purposes, but you don't need it at all, only the HTML part. And of course, you could use `text-left`, `text-right`, `text-justify`, etc. See [Bootstrap Type Alignment](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) for complete list

Comment: yes, it's a default class with Bootstrap. Really, I won't endorse in any way your childish behavior, I wanted to help the OP, your problems are out of my concerns. I appreciate the fact that you loved my answer so much that you edited yours to reflect EXACTLY what I said, at least someone is learning something. But seriously, grow up, I can't entertain children other than mine. But please, leave the OP out of your childish wars

Comment: pointing out the flaws in your explanation is more helpful than childish :)

Comment: the fact that you changed your wrong answer to mine shows that there wasn't a single flaw. Are you aware that I can see your edits?

Comment: Hi @Fabio, thanks for the reply. For some reason, they're still showing up on two separate lines :/

Comment: well, it will entirely depend on something else you have, as you may see in the Bootply, as long as you use the defaults, it owrks like a charm. If you have something else, you need to include it since I don't know

Answer (score 1):

I found in your code you are using `col-sm-3` which is not applicable for smaller devices like mobile rather it will work for tablet and desktop etc. we know that bootstrap grid system has divided our device screen with 12 equal parts if we will use `col-xs-6` for our both div then it will divide our device screen into two equal part whether it is a mobile or tablet... doesn't matter. Then I used bootstrap `text-center` class for making the inside element centered align, bootstrap center-align class which is nothing but `text-align:center;` in our plain css.

Try the below piece of code. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/540c3xe7/)

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-center"> 
            <a href="/bat-times/week">      
                <button class="btn btn-red"> Test 1</button>
            </a>    
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
            <a href="#"> 
                <button class="btn btn-yellow" onclick="checkTime()">Test 2</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found in your code you are using col-sm-3 which is not applicable for smaller devices like mobile rather it will work for tablet and desktop etc. we know that bootstrap grid system has divided our device screen with 12 equal parts if we will use col-xs-6 for our both div then it will divide our device screen into two equal part whether it is a mobile or tablet... doesn't matter. Then I used bootstrap text-center class for making your bootstrap center align which is nothing but text-align:center; in our plain css.

Comment: Just didnt want it to get overlooked :) It was a good explanation and bit of code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**TYPE 1**

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 row">
                    <a href="/bat-times/week">
                        <button class="btn btn-red pull-right">Test 1</button>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 row">
                    <a href="#">
                        <button class="btn btn-yellow pull-left" onclick="checkTime()">Test 2</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

## [DEMO1](http://www.bootply.com/BxhvOsQdJ9)

**TYPE 2**

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <a href="/bat-times/week">
                    <button class="btn btn-red">Test 1</button>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <button class="btn btn-yellow" onclick="checkTime()">Test 2</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

## [DEMO2](http://www.bootply.com/RUwFtpKlmq)